# Bulma Fill Box Within Child Tile

Tags: css, bulma

I have the [following tiling setup](https://codepen.io/PZ01/pen/Jpyjwg?editors=1100). How do I go about filling the rest of the space that is available under the first tile with text *Some Text* to match the height of the two narrower tiles that follow? I'd like to expand the content area below the image to the height of the two tiles that follow to the right, have them all even.

```
<div class="tile is-ancestor">
  <div class="tile is-parent is-6">
    <div class="tile is-child ">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/640x320.png">
      </figure>
      <div class="box">
        <h1 class="title">One</h1>
        <h6 class="subtitle is-7">Some Text</h6>
        <nav class="level">
          <div class="level-left">
            <div class="level-item">
              <font-awesome-icon :icon="iconUser" transform="shrink-3" class="icon-violet" />
              <a href="#">dd</a>
            </div>
            <div class="level-item">
              <a href="#">Today</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tile is-parent">
    <div class="tile is-child ">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/640x320.png">
      </figure>
      <div class="box">
        <h1 class="title">One</h1>
        <h6 class="subtitle is-7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed scelerisque dictum semper. Donec ornare ullamcorper velit, sagittis venenatis neque varius mattis. Suspendisse et lectus sed neque tincidunt convallis. Curabitur feugiat diam non tortor
          hendrerit, id mattis dui laoreet...</h6>
        <nav class="level">
          <div class="level-left">
            <div class="level-item">
              <a href="#">dd</a>
            </div>
            <div class="level-item">

              <a href="#">Today</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tile is-parent">
    <div class="tile is-child ">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/640x320.png">
      </figure>
      <div class="box">
        <h1 class="title">One</h1>
        <h6 class="subtitle is-7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed scelerisque dictum semper. Donec ornare ullamcorper velit, sagittis venenatis neque varius mattis. Suspendisse et lectus sed neque tincidunt convallis. Curabitur feugiat diam non tortor
          hendrerit, id mattis dui laoreet...</h6>
        <nav class="level">
          <div class="level-left">
            <div class="level-item">
              <a href="#">dd</a>
            </div>
            <div class="level-item">
              <a href="#">Today</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img
  height: 160px
  width: 100%
  display: block
  object-fit: cover
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the **Card** component instead of **Tiles**?

Comment: I'm learning Bulma, didn't consider them. Sounds like something I'll want to try out. I liked how tiles behaved likes columns, but perhaps I could put each cards into columns of the size I want and get similar results.